# Change charset from utf-8

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, character-encoding, angular

I recently started to learn Angularjs 2, I don't have much experience in Angular 1 and I'm following [their docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/).

I need to write in brazilian portuguese and I usually insert a charset of `iso-8859-1` in my HTML's head. When I used my html in Angular structure the charset wasn't recognised anymore.

This is the example that I'm using to test. When I use this html in the Angular template or its main index the charset is not recognised.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <title>João Paulo's site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>João Paulo</h1>
    <h2>áéíóú ÁÉÍÓÚ çõ</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If personal preference is the only factor here, I suggest you change that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved despite I'm not sure why. As my page was evolving I started to load the page's content by a external json file.

I'm still confused about utf-8 and iso-8859-1, but what solved the problem was to let the html page charset as utf-8 and I had to save the json file as iso-8859-1.